# Limitar maxlength en vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Quiero limitar el campo *input* con un *maxlength*, he intentando así;

```
<input class="input" type="number" v-model.number="numero" maxlength="10">
```

pero *vue.js* no lo reconoce.

```
<input class="input" v-model.number="numero" type="number">
```

Comment: `.length` es un propiedad de los datos tipo `string` no de los datos tipo `number`. Cuando haces el _cast_ a number, entonces ya no puedes validarlo por longitud, pero podrías hacerlo por valor.

Comment: Deberías crear un [mcve], consigo ejecutar el código que pones, pero no obtengo el mismo resultado. Aparte, como bien indica @toledano, `maxlength` es para campos de tipo string y no va a funcionar con números. Podrías usar `max` y `min`, pero no sé si eso es lo que buscas. Otra opción sería hacer el campo de tipo texto y ponerle una regla de validación para comprobar que sólo contiene números

Answer (score 5):

El atributo `maxlength` solo aplica a cajas de texto que almacenan strings, no a números. Tienes algunas opciones, ahora se me ocurren dos maneras: usando una librería de validación y usando un handler para el evento `input`.

Con una librería como [vee-validate](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate) es bastante sencillo:

```js
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    numero: null,
  })
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vee-validate/2.0.0-beta.25/vee-validate.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input 
    class="input" 
    type="number" 
    v-model.number="numero"
    name="numero"
    v-validate="'required|numeric|max:10'"
  />
  <span v-show="errors.has('numero')">
    {{ errors.first('numero') }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba haciendo algo asi:

Emplear el V-Validator.

O Asi:

```
<input type="text" name="numero" v-model.number="numero" v-validate:numero="{required: true, maxlength: 15}"/>
```

Sacado de:

```
https://blog.midkemia.fr/form-validation-with-vue-js/
```

Cabe destacar que puse `maxlength` por inercia. revisando la documentacion de vue.js en ningun lugar aparecia: `maxlength`, solo `minlegth`

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por sus respuestas, pero lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

```
<input class="input" onKeyUp="if(this.value>9){this.value='9';}else if(this.value<0){this.value='0';}" v-model.number="numero" type="number">
```

Lo dejo por si alguien lo llega a ocupar.